# When does 彼 refer to a person of indeterminate gender?

Tags: pronouns, gender

I've seen 彼 and even sometimes 彼氏 described in several dictionaries as a pronoun that can refer to a person of any gender, while 彼女 is explicitly female.  However in the wild ive never seen a woman referred to with 彼, but its also possible i dont see it, just as a second-language speaker of English may not realize "his" in "Every man must choose his fate" can refer to a person of any gender as it's a very subtle distinction.

So my question is this — when in modern day practice can 彼 refer to a person of either gender?

Comment: I think including those relevant dictionary definitions would make for a better question.

Comment: What you are referencing is called "markedness" in linguistic. Native Japanese speakers use pronouns much less frequently in Japanese than native English speakers use pronouns in English.

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BD%BC_%28%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8C%29/

Definition 2 here. 彼 without regard for gender is pretty archaic.

Comment: @Aeon Right, the definition you linked says right in it that it’s not longer used. So I was wondering dictionary OP was using that made it unclear.

Comment: Maybe that's obvious to others, and not to me perhaps because I am not an English native speaker, but how come "Every _man_ ..." can refer to a person of any gender?

Comment: Also, what about the [singular _they_ used as a gender neutral pronoun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they)? Something like "everyone must choose _their_ fate".

Comment: @jarmanso7 "Man" is synonymous with "person".  See also "mankind".  However "man" is a very masculine word, so it would be weird to say "Every man must choose her fate", even if from context its clear the speaker is speaking on a principle or fact that applies to everyone.

Comment: @cgottsch Sorry, I still don't get how it can be both synonymous with person and masculine at the same time. Person is not masculine, it is neutral. Is it really the case that "man" can be used to refer to woman, too? Maybe you can show some example sentences? I've found some information stating that in literary contexts, man can be gender neutral and it kind of means the mankind. But we are talking of specific individuals here, _every_ man, not the mankind as a whole, so I'm not convinced.

Comment: I mean. Okay, let's accept that man is a synonymous term for person. Then "Every man must choose her fate" should be acceptable, too. I smell a contradiction...

Comment: @jarmanso7 Whoops i meant to type parasynonym, not synonym.  My bad.

Answer (score 3):

彼{かれ} always refers to a male person in modern Japanese.

Historically, it was used to refer to something far away (like あれ in modern Japanese), and as a result was compatible with females as well, but that usage is no longer possible. Vestiges of that usage can be seen in 彼{か}の〜 (largely equivalent to あの) which is still used in modern Japanese.

Comment: And in fact the etymology of 彼女 is 彼{か}の女.

Answer (score -1):

The meaning of 彼 depends on the reading. If it's read かれ and is singular (i.e., not 彼ら), then it refers to a male.

Comment: 彼ら literally refers to something like '(the guy we were talking about) and others in his group', so while there can be females in that group, 彼 is still referring to a man. So it's less a function of 彼's meaning changing and more just how ら works.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie 彼's meaning does change, based on the reading. It's not always read かれ and doesn't always refer to a man.

Comment: If you are talking about 彼{か}, sure. I was responding to your parenthetical note about 彼ら.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie The paren was just to avoid suggesting that 彼ら refers only to males. For the other readings, I was thinking in terms of あ and あれ. So this was a misunderstanding I guess.